# What if we don't use split ring commutator in a DC motor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electricity

The book mentions that the direction of the current in an arm of the coil will always remain same if we don't use split ring commutator. But I am struggling to get this point. Just wanted to know about a DC motor that is without a commutator, if any and where is the problem in the working of such a motor? Pictorial answers would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Cosider the simplest of motors, one with a single coil of wire within a fixed magnetic field. The split ring commutator is a primitive switch so the that DC electricity goes through the coil one way, and then reverses the current when the armature turns 180 degrees. Without a split ring commutator the current would not reverse when armature reverses, and the magnetic fields of the rotor and stator would clash and the rotor will stick in a position and not turn.

Comment: What if we use a slip ring instead of a split ring? Will the current get reversed?